# Python version shipping with Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I would appreciate it if somebody running the final version of Snow Leopard could post what version of Python is included with the OS (on a Terminal, just type "python --version")

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html

Comment: Thanks! So 2.5, 2.6 and 3.0, with the default being Python 2.6.

Comment: Even though the document mentioned version 3.0, I don't seem to have it after upgraded to Snow Leopard. Only 2.5 and 2.6 exist.

Answer (score 12):

It ships with both python 2.6.1 and 2.5.4.

> $ python2.5
>
> Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:24)
>
> $ python
>
> Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51)

Answer (score 5):

```
bot:nasuni jesse$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Probably the biggest reason I went and upgraded this morning, it's not 2.6.2, but it's close enough.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.6.1

(according to the web)

Really good to know :)

Comment: "according to the web"?  Could you provide an actual link?

Comment: read: "various anecdotal accounts," a reference doesn't help much. However, someone below has the real answer. Don't blame me for being accepted as the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an installer for 2.6.2 from python.org, no reason to go without.